# Change the ordering of facets in facet_wrap

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to plot some information using `facet_wrap` but by default, the ordering of titles is alphabetical. The titles of my facets are month names and I would want them to be in a proper sequence (Jan, Feb, Mar....). I'm using the following code:

```
q<-ggparcoord(data = avgRevenueBySubject,
              columns = 1:9,  
              showPoints = FALSE, 
              alphaLines = 0.3,
              groupColumn="Type",
              shadeBox = NULL,
              scale = "globalminmax",
              title = "Average revenue from unique customers trained each month starting 2014(Jan-Jun)"
)
# data to merge
mm <- cbind.data.frame(.ID=1:nrow(avgRevenueBySubject), Month=avgRevenueBySubject$Month)
#merge data
q$data<-merge(q$data, mm)
#finish plot commands
q <- q+ geom_vline(aes(xintercept=3.5),color='blue',linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  facet_wrap(~Month,scales='fixed', nrow = 2) + geom_line(size=2)
q <- q + theme_minimal() + xlab('Months') + ylab('Average Revenue (Dollars)') +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0, angle=0), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=45),
        plot.title = element_text(size=20)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#a6cee3','#1f78b4','#b2df8a','#33a02c','#fb9a99'))
q
```

to generate the following plot:

[image]

Here's the output of `dput(head(avgRevenueBySubject))`

```
structure(list(Month1 = c(27.42, 0, 30.1363636363636, 11.8138888888889, 
5.19, 18.8727272727273), Month2 = c(22.23, 0, 39.5727272727273, 
5.89444444444444, 0, 25.7727272727273), Month3 = c(23.96, 7.41428571428571, 
40.2954545454545, 18.6222222222222, 5.19, 18.9181818181818), 
    Month4 = c(39.27, 14.55, 6.9, 24.9583333333333, 28.95, 23.5318181818182
    ), Month5 = c(49.58, 7.41428571428571, 30.3136363636364, 
    14.8638888888889, 18.96, 16.3363636363636), Month6 = c(52.11, 
    3.70714285714286, 67.6727272727273, 14.4638888888889, 34.95, 
    34.6772727272727), Month7 = c(31.81, 29.1, 28.6090909090909, 
    15.5333333333333, 20.37, 25.5954545454545), Month8 = c(20.76, 
    3.70714285714286, 21.2318181818182, 21.1833333333333, 14.97, 
    23.2363636363636), Month9 = c(56.01, 3.70714285714286, 11.7954545454545, 
    27.2111111111111, 19.17, 41.5727272727273), Type = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CC Delivery", "eServices", 
    "Filing", "ProcessServing", "Research"), class = "factor"), 
    Month = structure(1:6, .Label = c("April", "February", "January", 
    "June", "March", "May"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Month1", 
"Month2", "Month3", "Month4", "Month5", "Month6", "Month7", "Month8", 
"Month9", "Type", "Month"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to have these facets ordered in a chronological order. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: make the `Month` column an ordered factor: `factor(Month, labels=month.name[1:6], ordered=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. If you convert this to an answer, I'd be able to accept it. Thanks again !